# Thai Font in Django PDF

Tags: python, xhtml2pdf

I generate pdf file by django but It's not work for Thai Font

util.py

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

When I run , It's show ugly. Like This

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0OUg.png

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with xhtml2pdf, not django itself.  So you might have more success looking in that lib than in Django.  Secondly, its a bad idea to pass in a mutable as a default parameter:  https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Answer (score 0):

To add Thai font in invoice.html

```html
<style type="text/css">

            @font-face {
            font-family: "THSarabunNew";
            src: url("/home/pinsz/THSarabunNew.ttf");
            }

            body {
                font-weight: 200;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-family: "THSarabunNew";
            }
</style>
```

**Example Thai text:**
[image]